# storage space for mobile app using html and js

Tags: javascript, json, html

Okay, we talk and hear lot about creating mobile app using javascript and html. I was trying to write one app myself forgetting that some real programs also need to store and access at least, the information stored by the program. I intend to user only the browser of the mobile app and it is offline. Basically, it is just a program written using js. Since the browser is not allowed to create and store the data in the user's disk, how should I approach it? Storing the data in cookies is one of the option, I guess. I am new to web programming so please bear with me if I say something stupid. However, cookies can be inadvertently deleted.

So my question is: How can I manage a 'small storage space' in mobile device if I am using a html and js to create my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web storage is supported by almost all modern browsers
http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

If you are looking for offline web applications, it is not supported from old Internet Explorer
http://caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps

Here are a couple of useful links:
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html
http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe all modern phones support [LocalStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Comment: Thank you. I am looking into it right now. Sorry if I looked stupid in asking this but I just talking right off programming and based on my experience of desktop application.

Comment: You don't look stupid.  It's hard to Google based on a *need* -- you need the name of the thing.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5, there are a couple of ways to save information the way you want.
[LocalStorage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) and [WebDatabase](http://html5demos.com/database)

Although, if you want to do an App for iOS I recoment [Web Apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneWebApp/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008134), that allow you to create offline HTML application that the user see as a normal app.